# Second argument replacing first scala

Tags: arrays, scala, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to define a function in scala ( ^ ), which takes 2 values and prints them like

```
 2
x
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
class $ (val text2D: Array[Array[Char]])
{
  def ^(that: $) =
  {
    " " ++ s"${this.text2D(0)(0)}" ++
    "\n" ++ s"${that.text2D(0)(0)}"
  }

  def +(that: $) = this.text2D + "+" + that.text2D

  override def toString = s"${this.text2D(0)(0)}"
}

object $ {
  val array = Array.ofDim[Char](1,1)
  def apply(x: String): $ = {
    array (0)(0) = x.charAt(0)
    new $ (array)
  }
}

val x = $("x")
println(x)

val x2 = $("x") ^ $("2")
println(x2)
```

When I run this, I do not get the output I am expecting, instead I get

```
 2
2
```

Why is it only taking the second element? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`object` creates a singleton, so the (mutable) array that you use is shared between calls to `apply`. You need to allocate that array *inside* the `apply` call.

```
def apply(x: String): $ = {
  val array = Array.ofDim[Char](1,1)
  array (0)(0) = x.charAt(0)
  new $ (array)
}
```

Also, slightly unrelated, but I believe you have your arguments backward. To get the output you want, you need

```
" " ++ s"${that.text2D(0)(0)}" ++
"\n" ++ s"${this.text2D(0)(0)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
class $(val text2D: Array[String]) {
  def ^(that: $): $ = {
    if (this.text2D.length == 0)
      that
    else if (that.text2D.length == 0)
      this
    else {
      val thisW = this.text2D(0).length
      val thatW = that.text2D(0).length

      // cross-pad arrays to have the same width
      val padThisRight = " " * thatW
      val padThatLeft = " " * thisW
      val thisPaddedW = this.text2D.map(_ + padThisRight)
      val thatPaddedW = that.text2D.map(padThatLeft + _)
      // first lines comes from that!
      new $(thatPaddedW ++ thisPaddedW)
    }
  }

  def +(that: $): $ = {
    if (this.text2D.length == 0)
      that
    else if (that.text2D.length == 0)
      this
    else {
      val thisH = this.text2D.length
      val thatH = that.text2D.length
      val thisW = this.text2D(0).length
      val thatW = that.text2D(0).length

      // pad arrays to have the same height
      val emptyThis = " " * thisW
      val emptyThat = " " * thatW
      val thisPaddedH = if (thisH >= thatH) this.text2D else Array.fill(thatH - thisH)(emptyThis) ++ this.text2D
      val thatPaddedH = if (thisH <= thatH) that.text2D else Array.fill(thisH - thatH)(emptyThat) ++ that.text2D

      new $(thisPaddedH.zip(thatPaddedH).map(p => p._1 + p._2))
    }
  }

  override def toString = text2D.mkString("\n")
}

object $ {
  def apply(x: String): $ = {
    new $(Array[String](x))
  }
}
```

and then

```
val x2 = $("x") ^ $("2")
println(s"x2:\n$x2")
println("----------------------------")

val z = x2 + $(" + ") + y2
println(s"z:\n$z")
println("----------------------------")

val zz = x2 + $(" + ") + (y2 ^ $("3"))
println(s"zz:\n$zz")
println("----------------------------")
```

produces following output

```
x2:
 2
x 
----------------------------
z:
 2    2
x  + y 
----------------------------
zz:
       3
 2    2 
x  + y  
----------------------------
```

The main idea here is that operations on `$` produce another instance of `$` rather than `String` (I use `String` instead of `Array[Char]` as it seems much easier and has no obvious drawbacks). In such way you don't have to re-parse `String` splitting it by new lines and have to wonder how to handle cases when the string is not well-aligned. So now operators `^` and `+` is just an exercise in aligning two 2d-arrays to have either the same width or the same height and then joining them.